# Cannot remove .COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp in .git folder

Tags: git

I have tried "rm .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp", however it is throwing the error: cannot unlink : permission denied What gives?

I am using BASH on windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, that looks like the swap file created by vi(m) while editing a commit message.  Are you in the middle of doing that, or did vi(m) get interrupted?  What are the permissions on the file?  `ls -l .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp`.

Comment: Vim got interrupted because I am a noob trying to get my feet wet :/
The permissions are read and write (-rw-r--r--) correct?

Comment: OK, the answer to the first question makes sense.  The user has read/write privileges, but the group and other users can only read.  The `ls -l` command should also tell you the owner (and group).  On second thought, if you want to remove the file, I think what matters are the permissions on the diectory:  `ls -ld .git`.

Comment: Permissions on the director show drwxr-xr-x. I tried to chmod the directory and the file itself, however, that didn't do anything to the permissions. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: You are still not telling me who the owner and group are.  If the permissions are "rwxr-xr-x" you should break that into three:  "rwx", "r-x", "r-x".  The first group of three describes the owner's permissions, in this case read, write, and execute.  The second describes the group permissions, in this case read and execute.  The third describes the permissions of other users.  If you look at the full output of `ls -l`, then it will tell you who the owner and group are.